# Can a force be applied to 2 different points in same time?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction

So i was reading about how friction help us move. But how the friction that prevent our foot from not slipping and also help us accelerate? do the friction act in our foot and our center of mass in same time ?is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

For a rigid body to accelerate, the external force does not have to be applied to its center of mass - it will be passed from the application point to other points of the body through the internal stresses.

This is more obvious if you consider simple rigid bodies. For instance, you can hold a hockey stick at one end and still accelerate it, rotationally or translationally.

A human body could be treated as a system of rigid bodies, so, if appropriate muscles are engaged and appropriate joints are stiffened, the force of friction will be passed from the foot to other parts of the body and get it to move.

Answer (score 1):

No the friction force acts at your foot, not on your centre of mass. **Internal forces** in your body transmit the friction force to each part of your body so that all of it accelerates, not only the layer of atoms in contact with the ground.

The internal forces keep your body parts joined together in a semi-rigid structure. If they did not exist the soles of your feet would accelerate while the rest of your body stood still.

Answer (score 0):

Friction act at the point of contact but in order to consider the transition effect we considered as the friction is acting on the centre of mass. If we have to see the rotational effect then we consider at that point only. *Position of centre of mass cannot be moved  until and unless we apply some external force. Hence friction is necessary to walk  or even move a vehicle.*